# Timming desynchronization when rendering two elements with DirectX

Tags: directx

I want to render two boxes that change the color at the exact same time. I am using DirectX and measuring when they change the color with a photoresistor attached to the screen (measures change of luminance).

The two boxes change from black to white every 200ms. They should change at the same time but I am measuring latencies of 0-20ms. Is there any option to force DirectX to render at the exact same time?

```
OnTimer_Elapsed(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (i/2==1) 
      clr=clrWhite
  else 
      clr=clrBlack
  i++;

 d2dRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
 d2dRenderTarget.Clear(clrTrans);
 d2dRenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rect1, clr);
 d2dRenderTarget.FillRectangle(rect1, clr);
 d2dRenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rect2, clr);
 d2dRenderTarget.FillRectangle(rect2, clr);

 d2dRenderTarget.EndDraw();
 sc1.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
}
```

This is the swapchain

```
 sc1= new SwapChainDescription()
 {
    BufferCount = 1,                                 
    Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
    IsWindowed = true,                               
    ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(
       this.ClientSize.Width,                       
       this.ClientSize.Height,                      
       new Rational(60, 1),                          
       Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),                     
    OutputHandle = frm.Handle,                      
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
  };
```

Comment: Do you have vsync enabled? Are the boxes side-by-side or one above another? (I suspect you're measuring the scanline update of your monitor rather than anything directx related)

Comment: One box is in the middle of the screen, the other in the bottom right corner. How do I enable vsync?

Comment: I'm using Present(1, PresentFlags.None). That's vsync on, right?

Comment: I believe that's vsync on, yes. If the boxes placed side by side does the latency disappear/reduce?

Comment: What are the values of monitor latency and photoresistor latency? 20ms seems like an ok-ish latency for a typical IPS panel.

Comment: What do you mean by monitor latency and photoresistor latency?

Comment: The latency reduces if the boxes are placed side by side. However, doesn't directx supoose to render everything at once?